# SQL Deleting data based on max value of column

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I am looking to delete data from a table based on the max value of an index column - 23. Error received is 'In valid use of group function'

Currently Have:

```
DELETE FROM Raw_Data 
WHERE
    Raw_Data.Date_Index > MAX(`Date_Index`) - 23
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
DELETE rd
    FROM Raw_Data rd CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT MAX(Date_Index) as maxdi FROM Raw_data) m
    WHERE rd.Date_Index > maxdi - interval 23 days;
```

Note:  This uses `CROSS JOIN`.  You can put the condition in an `ON` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause.  I'm leaving it in this format because it more closely matches the query in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Raw_Data 
WHERE
    Raw_Data.Date_Index > (Select MAX(Date_Index) - 23 from Raw_Data)
```